# Is there a more efficient way to compare multiple float values in an If statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently just use something like this:

```
def match9(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i):
if a==b and b==c and c==d and d==e and e==f and f==g and g==h and h==i:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

in conjunction with

```
temp = match9(d1s1,d1s2,d1s3,d1s4,d1s5,d1s6,d1s7,d1s8,d1s9)
if temp == 1:
    codeToBeActivated()
```

Comment: More efficient in terms of what?  Time?  Space?  Or code?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `==` to compare `float`s in the first place.

Comment: Well, it seems that you want to check if all the items are equal, so you simply `set()` in order to preserve the unique items and count the length of result.

Comment: `def match9(*args): return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x == y, args)` – though, yes, `==` and floats don't mix well.

Comment: [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Comment: @Kasramvd: Comparing floats for **exact** equality is rarely useful; please see CoryKramer's link.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah I saw it, but since OP doesn't mentioned anything about the quality of equality and also he is looking for a alternative for `==`, I preferred this duplicate.

Comment: Another option (not great on efficiency, but still): collect all variable to a list x = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i). Then check if max([abs(x[k]-x[k+1]) for k in range(len(x)-1)])==0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a shortcut

```
if a == b == c == d == e == f == g == h == i:
```

That being said, using `==` to compare `float`s can lead to errors because of floating point precision (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)). You can try checking the differences between elements. Here is an example for Python >= 3.4:

```
from statistics import stdev
if stdev([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]) < 1e-6:  # Or some other threshold
```